# Can I trust URLSubmit?

Tags: bugs, web-access, scheduling, asynchronous-processing

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier and solved in V13.2**

> [CASE:4026293] confirmed

---

Let's create 10 asynchronous requests which just check if the site is there.

```
Do[
  URLSubmit[
    "www.wolfram.com"
  , HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"StatusCode"}
  , HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskFinished" -> Print|>
  ]
, {10}
]
```

Now, depending of Jupiter's position in the sky I get 1 to 7 `{}` results instead of a valid association:

[image]

What do I do wrong?

It happens when each url is different too.

Comment: I don't think it is a timeout issue. I used Fiddler to see what was going on and it registered 10 identical request and 10 identical responses.

Comment: Mathematica desperately needs [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Isn't already much of Mathematica a promise? There is documentation which promises something, but the promise may or may not be kept. It's a function of time, kind of asynchronous ... (version x.y.z may work in the future some time )

Comment: `Do[Pause[.137]; 
 URLSubmit["www.wolfram.com", HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"StatusCode"}, 
  HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskFinished" -> Print|>], {10}]` works for me ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74187/discussion-on-question-by-kuba-can-i-trust-urlsubmit).

Comment: "Can I trust [anything in Mathematica]?" => pretty sure the answer is no

Comment: @LeonidShifrin https://gist.github.com/Kreijstal/2a34158a1cf159b4ddc5ab3460f6efd0 this is my attempt but I am too lazy to do error handling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bug confirmed:

> [...] The source of the issue unknown to us at this point; however, it seems that all the request are submitted, yet tasks finishes prematurely, before getting the status code. [...]

So before it gets fixed we can use `URLFetchAsynchronous`:

```
statusHandler[obj_, "statuscode", {statusCode_}] := Print@<|"StatusCode" -> statusCode|>;

Do[
 URLFetchAsynchronous["www.wolfram.com", statusHandler],
 {10}
]
```

Answer (score 10):

This is indeed a racing condition due to `TaskObject` is created from `AsynchronousTaskObject` with default value to `AutoRemove` which is `True`.

The task is removed manually in 'finished' handler (which fails in some cases due to task is already auto removed). In this case task event data is empty so no status code.

To verify this:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
PrintDefinitions @ URLSubmit
```

find the lines

```
spec = <|...|>;
res = AsyncToTaskObject@spec;
```

add `AutoRemove -> False` to the spec and press Shift-Enter (you should see 'patched' in the status line).

After that `URLSumbit` works flawlessly for me.